# Rails 3.2 where is fragment cached data getting stored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have created rails application and I have used fragment caching concept. Where is cached data getting stored and how can I access those data? How do I know whether caching is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [fragment caching docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/files/actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching/fragments_rb.html) for references (you are particularly interested in [ActionController::Caching::Fragments](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html)).

You may want to check

```
ActiveSupport::Cache.expand_cache_key(key, namespace)
```

to check specific key for whether it is being cached.

To check the cache storage you can check the

```
 config.action_controller.page_cache_directory
```

P.S. It's high time to upgrade your Rails version ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I saw the documentation still I don't know where the cached data getting stored ?

Comment: @anandh I'm pretty sure it's stored in default cache store (check what the default cache store was in rails 3.2) - can't check at the moment (off the laptop)

Comment: @Andery: Thanks for your response. Will try it.

Comment: @anandh check this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/caching_with_rails.html - there search for "by default" (third occurrence)

Comment: @anandh its `config.action_controller.page_cache_directory`

Comment: I have code like config.action_controller.cache_store = :memory_store

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130203/discussion-between-anandh-and-andrey-deineko).

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I got the solution.

Cached data will stored based on cache_store used in environment configuration.

Ex)

Some available cache_stores are memory_store, file_store,.. etc

I have configured file_store in development environment then the data will be stored in rails_root/tmp/cache directory

Comment: I think it is exactly what I was trying to say: check the cache storage used in your app and this will be the place where data is being stored...